# DynamoDB REMOVE event is only returning HASH and RANGE values, not all the keys

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I have a DynamoDB table with a TTL column.
The record expires correctly. I have set the stream to OLD_IMAGE.

I have a Lambda that listens to it.

However, in the returned object I only see key/value pairs - matching my RANGE and HASH keys.

Is there a way for the OLD_IMAGE from the REMOVE event to have all the values from the table?

Answer (score 0):

It should contain all values, can you follow https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/automatically-archive-items-to-s3-using-dynamodb-time-to-live-with-aws-lambda-and-amazon-kinesis-firehose/ ? It's pretty hard to see the exact issue without looking at the environment.